# Python - Problem with creating an impossibility

Tags: python

I have this function that looks at the result of the tab (which is a board that consists of a tuple with three tuples and each smaller tuple has three elements that can only be 1,-1 or 0). This is basically a tic tac toe board where 1 represents X, -1 represents O and 0 = nothing played. I want my function to return the number of the player that won (1 or -1 and if it is a draw then returns 0) but it will return a ValueError if I put a tab that has 2 players that both won. I'll give some examples (think of each smaller tuple as the first, second and third line of the tic tac toe board):

- `tab = ((1,1,1),(-1,-1,-1),(0,0,0))`  - This is an impossibility, however returns '1'
- `tab = ((1,1,-1),(0,1,-1),(0,0,1))`   - Returns 1

Here is my code. You can ignore the first three functions:

```
def eh_tabuleiro(tab):
    if len(tab) != 3:  
        return False
    else:  
        for row in tab:
            if len(row) != 3: 
                return False
            else: 
                for element in row:
                    if element not in (-1, 0, 1):
                        return False
        return True

def obter_coluna(tab, c): 
    if eh_tabuleiro(tab):
        if c == 1:
            return (tab[0][0],tab[1][0],tab[2][0])
        elif c == 2:
            return (tab[0][1],tab[1][1],tab[2][1])
        elif c == 3:
            return (tab[0][2],tab[1][2],tab[2][2])
        else:
            return ValueError('obter_coluna: algum dos argumentos e invalido')
    else:
        return ValueError('obter_coluna: algum dos argumentos e invalido')    
    
def obter_linha(tab, l): 
    if eh_tabuleiro(tab):
        if l == 1:
            return (tab[0][0],tab[0][1],tab[0][2])
        elif l == 2:
            return (tab[1][0],tab[1][1],tab[1][2])
        elif l == 3:
            return (tab[2][0],tab[2][1],tab[2][2])
        else:
            return ValueError('obter_linha: algum dos argumentos e invalido')
    else:
        return ValueError('obter_linha: algum dos argumentos e invalido')    
    
def obter_diagonal(tab, d): 
    if eh_tabuleiro(tab):
        if d == 1:
            return (tab[0][0],tab[1][1],tab[2][2])
        elif d == 2:
            return (tab[2][0],tab[1][1],tab[0][2])
        else:
            raise ValueError('obter_diagonal: algum dos argumentos e invalido')
    else:
        raise ValueError('obter_diagonal: algum dos argumentos e invalido')


#This is the one I am having problems with

def jogador_ganhador(tab):
    if eh_tabuleiro(tab):
        #winner on the diagonal
        if sum(obter_diagonal(tab, 1)) == 3:
            return '1'     
        elif sum(obter_diagonal(tab, 1)) == -3:
            return '-1'
        elif sum(obter_diagonal(tab, 2)) == 3:
            return '1'      
        elif sum(obter_diagonal(tab, 2)) == -3:
            return '-1'
        #winner on the lines
        elif sum(obter_linha(tab, 1)) == 3:
            return '1'     
        elif sum(obter_linha(tab, 1)) == -3:
            return '-1'
        elif sum(obter_linha(tab, 2)) == 3:
            return '1'      
        elif sum(obter_linha(tab, 2)) == -3:
            return '-1'
        elif sum(obter_linha(tab, 3)) == 3:
            return '1'    
        elif sum(obter_linha(tab, 3)) == -3:
            return '-1'
        #winner on the columns 
        elif sum(obter_coluna(tab, 1)) == 3:
            return '1'     
        elif sum(obter_coluna(tab, 1)) == -3:
            return '-1'
        elif sum(obter_coluna(tab, 2)) == 3:
            return '1'      
        elif sum(obter_coluna(tab, 2)) == -3:
            return '-1'
        elif sum(obter_coluna(tab, 3)) == 3:
            return '1'    
        elif sum(obter_coluna(tab, 3)) == -3:
            return '-1'
        else: #draw
            return '0'
    else:
        raise ValueError('winner: the argument is invalid')
```

This last function basically does the addition of all lines, columns and diagonals and sees if the value is 3 (if player with X won) or -3 (if player with O won) but I don't understand how it doesn't return an Error if there is two winners and what I can do to change.

Comment: You only raise a `ValueError` if `eh_tabuleiro(tab)` returns `False`. It only returns `False` if the board (tab) doesn't have exactly three rows and three columns, or if any of it's elements are not 1, 0 or -1. In a board with two winners, none of these conditions are violated, and for any given winning configuration, you always check if player one occupies that configuration first. Therefore, even if there are two winners, you will not raise a `ValueError` exception, and player one will always be treated as the winner.

Comment: Then do I need to create a "if" for every combination of two winnings or more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you check only for a single row or column and fail to check others for inconsistency, so the solution is to check for inconsistency as well:

```
def jogador_ganhador(tab):
    if not eh_tabuleiro(tab): raise ValueError('winner: the argument is invalid')

    num_wins = []

    #winner on the diagonal
    if sum(obter_diagonal(tab, 1)) == 3:
        num_wins.append('1')
    if sum(obter_diagonal(tab, 1)) == -3:
        num_wins.append('-1')
    if sum(obter_diagonal(tab, 2)) == 3:
        num_wins.append('1')
    if sum(obter_diagonal(tab, 2)) == -3:
        num_wins.append('-1')

    #winner on the lines
    if sum(obter_linha(tab, 1)) == 3:
        num_wins.append('1')
    if sum(obter_linha(tab, 1)) == -3:
        num_wins.append('-1')
    if sum(obter_linha(tab, 2)) == 3:
        num_wins.append('1')
    if sum(obter_linha(tab, 2)) == -3:
        num_wins.append('-1')
    if sum(obter_linha(tab, 3)) == 3:
        num_wins.append('1')
    if sum(obter_linha(tab, 3)) == -3:
        num_wins.append('-1')

    #winner on the columns
    if sum(obter_coluna(tab, 1)) == 3:
        num_wins.append('1')
    if sum(obter_coluna(tab, 1)) == -3:
        num_wins.append('-1')
    if sum(obter_coluna(tab, 2)) == 3:
        num_wins.append('1')
    if sum(obter_coluna(tab, 2)) == -3:
        num_wins.append('-1')
    if sum(obter_coluna(tab, 3)) == 3:
        num_wins.append('1')
    if sum(obter_coluna(tab, 3)) == -3:
        num_wins.append('-1')

    if len(num_wins) > 1:
        raise ValueError('winner: the argument is invalid')

    return num_wins[0] if len(num_wins) else '0'
```

Comment: The indentation is wrong and I can't figure out the correct way

Comment: @Pedro, updated answwer with fixed indentation. I use 4 spaces but you can adjust